# Multiple Instances of UserControl not Binding

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, user-controls, windows-phone-8.1

Hi I tried to create a simple UserControl with TestValue1 and TestValue2 Properties and Created two Instances of it in a stack panel. But what is happening is that only the Last Control is storing the values in the User Control the rest have just blank values.

[image]

Here is the XAML code where they are used:

```
<userControls:TestControl TestValue1="Vasu" TestValue2="Mahesh"></userControls:TestControl>
<userControls:TestControl TestValue1="Test" TestValue2="Testing2"></userControls:TestControl>
```

Here is the UserControl's XAML and Code Behind:

Code Behind:

```
public sealed partial class TestControl : UserControl
    {
        public TestControl()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = this;
        }

        public readonly DependencyProperty TestValue1DependencyProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("TestValue1", typeof(string), typeof(TestControl), new PropertyMetadata(default(string)));
        public string TestValue1
        {
            get
            {
                return (string)GetValue(TestValue1DependencyProperty);
            }
            set
            {
                SetValue(TestValue1DependencyProperty, value);
            }
        }

        public readonly DependencyProperty TestValue2DependencyProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("TestValue2", typeof(string), typeof(TestControl), new PropertyMetadata(default(string)));
        public string TestValue2
        {
            get
            {
                return (string)GetValue(TestValue2DependencyProperty);
            }
            set
            {
                SetValue(TestValue2DependencyProperty, value);
            }
        }
    }
```

XAML File:

```
<UserControl
    x:Name="TestControlName"
    x:Class="downloader.UserControls.TestControl"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:downloader.UserControls"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="300"
    d:DesignWidth="400">

    <Grid>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding TestValue1 , ElementName=TestControlName}"></TextBlock>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding TestValue2 , ElementName=TestControlName}"></TextBlock>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved!

The Trick was with the DataContext :

in the XAML of the UserControl I set up:

```
<UserControl
    x:Name="TestControlName"
    x:Class="downloader.UserControls.TestControl"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:downloader.UserControls"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="300"
    d:DesignWidth="400">

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRootGrid">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding TestValue1}"></TextBlock>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding TestValue2}"></TextBlock>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

And in C# Code Behind:

```
//this.DataContext = this;
LayoutRootGrid.DataContext = this;
```

Probably because the DataContext was being Overridden by `this` ... Since DataContext is inherited from the Parent , by using the old line it was no longer inheriting from its parent.

So I gave the inner element the data context of the code behind which allowed the UserControl to inherit the DataContext of the Parent (i.e. from where it is called)